# Creating CSV connector for Kafka Connect

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm planning to write my own Kafka connect CSV connector which will read the data from a CSV file and write the data to a topic. Data should be written to the topic in the form of JSON.

Also I came across **kafka-connect-spooldir** plugin of confluent. I don't want to use this and write my own.

Can anyone advice me how to go about creating a connector for the same?

Comment: Note: The spooldir one is written by a Confluent employee, but not supported by them. Also you couldn't just fork that code, delete everything you think isn't needed, and redo it. That way, you have a starting point

Comment: if other people are also looking for a connector to read CSV files: https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse

Answer (score 0):

The official Kafka documentation has a [section on Connector development](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_development) so that is probably the best first stop.

Kafka also ships with File Connectors (both Source and Sink). Have a look at the code: https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file

It should not be too hard to modify these for your use case.

Finally as you mentioned, there are already connectors that can read CSV files and that are open source. So if you're stuck on something you can check how they did it.